# Netbeans Mercurial Authentication

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, basic-authentication, hgweb

I have a strange problem. I have set up a Mercurial server using the hgweb.cgi script. The script runs in a subfolder on my Apache webserver, and I use Apache basicauth to enforce authentication.

When I try to pull from my server using hg.exe on Windows, command line, it works fine. Also the push, incoming and outgoing commands are working. In Aptana, pushing and pulling also works fine.

Next step for me was to set up Mercurial in Netbeans. I cannot get it to work because I cannot authenticate. Netbeans keeps asking me for the un/pw combination. The attached window keeps popping up. No matter what I do, in the end I have to click the 'Cancel' button and I end up with an error:

```
Mercurial Pull 
-------------- 
INFO Pulling From: http://user:****@server.nl:8080/hg/kate ... 
ERROR Command failed: 
Command: [hg, incoming, -v, --bundle, C:\wamp\www\Thorium\Kate_bundle0, --repository,             C:\wamp\www\Thorium\Kate, http://user:****@server.nl:8080/hg/kate] 
Output: [abort: http authorization required] 
INFO: End of Mercurial Pull
```

Link to [the error message](http://forums.netbeans.org/files/netbeans_973.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching for the solutions... I finally got it to work. For everybody else who experiences this problem: an update of the TortoiseHG mercurial client fixed my problems! Apperently, Netbeans 7.0.1 and TortoiseHG 2.1.2 are not compatible. Updating to TortoiseHG 2.1.4 did the trick.